# Копирование и вывод строки массива

Tags: c#, массивы, winforms

Требуется вывести из матрицы A строку p в отдельный массив X, и столбец q в отдельный массив Y.Ниже приведён пример, где ошибка в неправильном имени массива(а именно в строке m.CopyTo(DGV_X[], 1);), как и на что заменить?

```
        int[] m = new int[DGV_A.RowCount]; //Матрица разбита на строки m и столбцы n для более удобного вывода 
        int[] n = new int[DGV_A.ColumnCount];
        int p1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text); // Ввод числа для получения строки p
        int q1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);  // Ввод числа для получения столбца q
        //индекс нужной строки
        int strok = 0;
        for (int p = 0; p < DGV_A.RowCount; p++)
            for (int q = 0; q < DGV_A.ColumnCount; q++)
            {
                m[p] = Convert.ToInt32(DGV_A[q, p].Value);
                strok = strok + 1;
                if (strok == p1)
                    m.CopyTo(DGV_X[], 1);
            }
```

Comment: Не экономьте на буквах, пишите понятные имена переменных, чтобы выдрав кусок кода можно было примерно понять для чего нужна переменная.

Comment: @ГеннадийП, уточнил, теперь лучше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно вам подойдёт такое решение:

```
int targetRow = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text); // Ввод числа для получения строки p
int rargetColumn = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);  // Ввод числа для получения столбца q

int[] x = new int[DGV_A.ColumnCount];
int[] y = new int[DGV_A.RowCount];

for (int currentColumn = 0; currentColumn < DGV_A.ColumnCount; currentColumn++)
{
    x[currentColumn] = Convert.ToInt32(DGV_A[currentColumn, targetRow].Value);
}

for (int currentRow = 0; currentRow < DGV_A.RowCount; currentRow++)
{
    y[currentRow] = Convert.ToInt32(DGV_A[rargetColumn, currentRow].Value);
}
```

Comment: мне кажется или ваш вариант это ручное заполнение?

Comment: В этом решении мы в цикле проходимся по целевой строке матрицы и присваиваем значения этой строки массиву `x` и проходимся по целевому столбцу матрицы (в другом цикле) и присваиваем значения массиму `y`. "В ручную" по прежнему вводятся только номер целевой строки и номер целевого столбеца (в первых двух строках ответа)

Comment: Можете ещё вывод оформить, а то без него не понятно, какой результат(точнее вообще НЕТ результата)